# Backup users in Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database

IN my scenario need to take azure sql database backup and restore in another azure sql database server.I have done it using Export and Import . But i need to take the backup of users from one DB to another with permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the script for creating a script that can be run on the exported/imported database to create users. Here is the script - 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190475/scripting-out-database-user-level-permissions

If the need is to move the On premises Logins to Azure SQL DB:There is a [utility](https://github.com/Microsoft/DataMigrationTeam/tree/master/IP%20and%20Scripts/MoveLogins) to move On-Premises SQL Server Logins to Azure SQL DB.

This scenario is documented in the Data Migration Assistant [guide](https://datamigration.microsoft.com/scenario/sql-to-azuresqldb?step=1)

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Navtej S